# Al firmar pdf borra datos de formulario (itextsharp vb.net)

Tags: pdf, itextsharp

Al insertar una firma digital con itextsharp a un pdf, me borra los datos de formulario. ¿Sabe alguien porqué?
Este es el código que uso:

```
Sub SignWithCertificate(ByVal src As String, ByVal dest As String)
        Dim certificate As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(rutapfx, passw, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
        Dim cp As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser = New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser()
        Dim chain As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() = New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() {cp.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData)}
        Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(src)
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)
        Dim stamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fs, vbNullChar, Nothing, True)
        Dim pks As IExternalSignature = New X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, "SHA-1")
        Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
        appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime
        appearance.Reason = razon
        appearance.Location = localizacion
        appearance.Acro6Layers = True
        appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED
        Dim signature As PdfSignature = New PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1)
        appearance.CryptoDictionary = signature
        Dim signatureChain = rutapfx
        Dim standard = CryptoStandard.CADES
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, standard)
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then reader.Close()
        If stamper IsNot Nothing Then stamper.Close()
    End Sub
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución, y la pongo aquí por si le sirve a alguien:

Los campos de formulario no desaparecen al FIRMAR, sino al EDITAR.
La solución consiste en poner a READ ONLY todos los campos de formulario.
Aprovecho también para bloquear las capas del pdf.
Este es el código que a mí me funcionó:

```
Sub BloquearForm(oldfile As String, newfile As String)
        'Si tenemos un formulario, bloqueamos todos los campos como de sólo lectura
        Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(oldfile)
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, fs)
        stamper.FormFlattening = True
        'ponemos a READ ONLY cada campo de formulario
        Dim fields() As String = stamper.AcroFields.Fields.[Select](Function(x) x.Key).ToArray()
        For key As Integer = 0 To fields.Count - 1
            stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(fields(key), "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, Nothing)
        Next
        'Bloqueamos las capas para que no se puedan modificar
        Dim capas = From cada In stamper.GetPdfLayers
        For Each capa In capas
            capa.Value.OnPanel = False
        Next
        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = False
        stamper.Close()
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Close()
        reader.Close()
    End Sub
```